# PHP Class to export data to QuickBooks import format?

Tags: php, csv, quickbooks

Seeing lots of SOAP/RDS stuff, but just want to dump some MySQL data and/or CSV files to IIF/QIF/OFX format and don't want to reinvent the wheel (laziness ensues).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not going to see much in the way of IIF/QIF/OFX imports for QuickBooks for good reason: IIF support is deprecated in QuickBooks, and QIF and OFX are not supported at all.

You can see some additional information here: 
 [QuickBooks integration methods](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_methods)

By far your best bet is to use the QuickBooks SDK and write a simple qbXML importer for yourself, or do the "right thing" and write a full SDK application using the Web Connector to import the data. qbXML is the transaction format supported by Intuit/the SDK, and the Web Connector provides an automated way to communicate with QuickBooks (both import and export of data).

There is a set of PHP classes here for communicating with QuickBooks: 
 [QuickBooks PHP Framework](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the code above. If you're still looking for IIF imports... get in touch with me as it's something I might be able to help you out with.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen one.

I have to do this from time to time, and it's basically an awkward reinvention of the wheel.

would love if someone proved me wrong!

This might help:
[Intuit Quickbooks Import/Export Forum](http://community.intuit.com/categories/contents/214)

Comment: Didn't see that.  Doh.  I'll give it a boo -- if someone there points me in the right direction, I'll post the answer here, and mark yours as the "accepted answer".

Comment: No dice on their Q/A forums.  Perhaps I need to unlazy myself and write one.