# is it possible to export data using php in iif format?

Tags: php

is it possible to export data in iif format using php? like we export data in csv or excel format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090062/php-class-to-export-data-to-quickbooks-import-format/1410427#1410427) suggests that IIF isn't supported any more but that there are libraries available to read/write similar formats.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to build a script that does this though.

See [this page for the format you need to output](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/Articles/HOW12778).

Basically you would do something similar to this:

```
 // Open the file for writing...
$fp = fopen("myiiffile.iif", "w");

//Loop through the records writing out the data in the proper format...

fwrite($fp, $inputstring);

//Close the file...
 fclose($fp);
```